# Oracle APEX - Space between cards in template "Cards"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to change the card spacing (in CSS). I've managed to change the horizontal margin in my styles, while the vertical margin I'm not able to change. (Apex 19.2)

[image]

example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=93624:1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the exact names are the same for you, but you should be able to find it anyway.

When you inspect the list it should be a `<ul>` element.

It's child `<li class="t-Cards-item">` has `<div class="t-Card">`

You can change the style of the `.t-Card` class in order to achieve what you want.

Setting `margin-left` or `margin-right` to your desired values should do the trick.

**EDIT:** Just looked at your link and it does work.
I attached the element I mean in the screenshot. It already has margin: 8px, but if you add the margin left and right you can change the space between the cards.

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer with a screenshot of the element in your example. It does work.

Comment: still not working: apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=93624:1 i added style to .t-Card margin-left and right 0.

Comment: It's OK. You had to remove it: width: 100%; (old: width calc(100% - 16px);

Comment: there was a hidden margin here!